# Count the amount of times each string appears in an array of strings using C#

Tags: c#

For this, I'm deriving code from a text file as strings, and I want to count the frequency of each of the strings. I got the counter to loop, but if the counter will display the result multiple times.

**How do I get it to recognize unique strings?**
**I want it to display this:**

> The number 1 appears 1 time
>
> The number 2 appears 4 times
>
> The number 4 appears 3 times

**But it's displaying this right now:**

> The number 1 appears 1 time
>
> The number 2 appears 4 times
>
> The number 2 appears 4 times
>
> The number 2 appears 4 times
>
> The number 2 appears 4 times
>
> The number 4 appears 3 times
>
> The number 4 appears 3 times
>
> The number 4 appears 3 times

```
void Start()
{
    string Random = "";

    // Read text 
    string Numbers_Path = Application.dataPath + "/Text_Files/Numbers.txt";
    string[] Duplicates = File.ReadAllLines(Numbers_Path);

    foreach (string number in Duplicates)
    {
        Random += number;
    }

    //output display text_file
    NumOutput.text = Random + "\n";

    Array.Sort(Duplicates);

    for (int x = 0; x < Duplicates.Length; x++)
    {
        count = Duplicates.Count(n => n == Duplicates[x]);
        Display += "The number " + Duplicates[x] + " appears " + count + " time/s" + "\n";
    }
            Results.text = Display;
```

Comment: It seems like a homework answered yesterday. The problem is `Duplicates` contains duplicate characters. So you keep repeat it multiple times.

Comment: I know it contains duplicates, but I want it to be unique and not repeat multiple times. I just need it to count each once. It should display each of them only once.

Comment: You need to ask a specific question. Eg: "I don't know how to eliminate duplicate characters.". By your current post, I'll assume you encounter just a logic bug you did not notice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Enumerable.GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netcore-3.1) to group the lines by the value(text value should be sufficient here). For example,

```
foreach(var number in Duplicates.GroupBy(x=>x))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"The number {number.Key} has appeared {number.Count()} times");
}
```

Breaking the solution into parts,**

**Step 1 : Input read from Text File**

```
var Duplicates = File.ReadAllLines(Numbers_Path);
```

[image]

**Step 2 : Grouping the Duplicate Collection by Value**

```
Duplicates.GroupBy(x=>x)
```

[image]

**Ouput : Final Result**

```
The number 1 has appeared 3 times
The number 2 has appeared 2 times
The number 3 has appeared 3 times
The number 5 has appeared 2 times
```

Comment: That visual expansion on the solution is golden and so helpful! Thank you for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need them in the original order for any other reason, you could use a `Dictionary<string, int>`.

If you got a string from the file, you check if it is already in the collection - and if so, increase the value by 1. If not, you add it to the collection with a value of 0. And you can do all that while reading the file, possibly even using a Enumerator to go over the lines.

I would also not worry about performance. `Dictionary<Key, Value>` is also the generic HashTable internally - so the string comparison will usually not be necessary during search and addition. And on top of that, strings are immutable and can be interned.

So the logic would probably go:

- Hash comparison
- Reference comparison
- Actually going of those chars

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for either Distinct (reduces to just the unique elements) or GroupBy (divides into groups by some criteria).
[See the LINQ reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable?view=netcore-3.1) for more details.

For example, using the latter could look like:

```
var counts = Duplicates
    .GroupBy(x => x)  // We're grouping by uniqueness, so use the entire value 
    .Select(g => $"{g.First()} appears {g.Count()} times");
Results.text = string.Join("\n", counts);
```